# AutoFit Row Height works when manually run on merged cells, but not in VB

Tags: excel, merge, vba

I am able to manually AutoFit Row Height on cells that have an Index/Match referencing merged cells, but when I use a Macro such as follows, it clears all the values out of the cell I am auto-fitting and sets my merged field value equal to #value. Here is the Macro I am using in Sheet 1 on the Purchases column:

```
Sub AutofitMerged()
Range("Sheet1[Purchases]").Select
Selection.Rows.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Here is the function I am using in Sheet 2 on the Merged Purchases column to merge cells with common IDs that are visible (I don't want filtered values being merged).

```
Function JoinAll(ByVal BaseValue, ByRef rng As Range, ByVal delim As String)
Application.Volatile
For Each a In rng
If a = BaseValue And a.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
JoinAll = JoinAll & IIf(JoinAll = "", "", delim) & a(1, 6)
End If
Next a
End Function
```

In the cell I am auto-fitting, I am using Index/Match to get the merged values from a second worksheet. The second worksheet is the one containing the merged field. My worksheets use the following architecture:

Sheet1

```
Client ID | Purchases 
1 | Purchase 1, Purchase 2 (Index/Match of Client 1 Purchases from Sheet 2)
2 | Purchase 3 (Index/Match of Client 2 Purchases from Sheet 2)
3 | Purchase 4, Purchase 5 (Index/Match of Client 3 Purchases from Sheet 2)
```

Sheet 2

```
Client ID | Purchase | Merged Purchases
1 | Purchase 1 | Purchase 1, Purchase 2
1 | Purchase 2 | Purchase 1, Purchase 2
2 | Purchase 3 | Purchase 3
3 | Purchase 4 | Purchase 4, Purchase 5
3 | Purchase 5 | Purchase 4, Purchase 5
```

My goal is to AutoFit the Row Height any time something changes, such as new purchases being entered in Sheet 2. I envisioned using Worksheet_Calculate or another appropriate automated function, but defer to the greater minds here.

Comment: Why was this marked down. It has proper references to the issue including sample data and code.